# Paired t-test for non-normal variable distributed R programming

Tags: r, statistical-test

I want to conduct Paired t-test for 2 variables that one is normal distributed and the other is not (N = 56)

I've used the Shapiro-Wilk in order to check normality of the variables and these are the results:

> **Shapiro-Wilk normality test**
>
> *data:  Bq_t1$var*
>
> W = 0.98041, p-value = 0.4932
>
> *data:  Bq_t2$var*
>
> W = 0.9261, p-value = 0.002072

As you can see, the second test came sig (p<0.05) so the var is not normal distributed.

Furthermore, the results of the T-test came significant but I'm not sure whether I can use this test.

> **Paired t-test**
>
> t = 7.8132, df = 55, p-value = 1.759e-10
>
> alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
>
> 95 percent confidence interval:
> 6.983627 11.802087
>
> sample estimates: mean of the differences
> 9.392857

what should I do?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: For a paired t-test we only care if the differences are approximately normally distributed.

Comment: I see, How do I check it?

Comment: Look at the distribution of the differences. With n of 56 as long as the distribution isn't too non-normal you should be more than fine.

Comment: you mean to plot a distribution  of var3 which is: var3=(var1 - var2)?

Comment: If you're thinking about doing a paired t-test then what you define as var3 should be the only variable you actually consider.  So yes you can plot the histogram or maybe a qq-plot for that variable.  Something along those lines just to assess if it's "too" non-normal or not.